# c++ derived class question

Tags: c++, oop

suppose I have this code:

```
class D : public Base1, Base2 {}
```

My question is. Obviously class D is public derived from Base1, but what about Base2? Is is private derived? Or also public derived?

I checked some websites but I did no find article about this.
thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's private derived, inheritance method should be declared for each base class individually, if not, then it's private by default.

Answer (score 3):

Class members are **private** by default and that holds for inheritance too. Also, class definition should end with a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Private. Unless it's declared as public, it will always be private by default.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly Base2 is private by default however you can specify access for that one as well, as in this example:

```
class D : public Base1, public Base2 {};
```